# Sum of partial group of {^(0),(1),……,()}

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion, console, combinations

I want to write a program where input are `x` and `y` integer values 
and then:

1. Let s be the set { x<sup>0</sup>, <sup>1</sup>, …, <sup>y</sup>}; store it in `array`.
2. Repeat:

   - Partition the set `s` into two subsets: `s1` and `s2`.
   - Find the sum of each of the two subset and store them in variables like `sum1`, `sum2`.
   - Calculate the product of `sum1 * sum2`.
3. The program ends after passing all over the partial groups that could be formed and then prints the max value of the product `sum1 * sum2`.
   example: suppose x=2 , y=3 s= {1,2,4,8} one of the divisions is to take s1 ={1,4} , s2={2,8} sum1=5 , sum2= 10 the product is 50 and that will be compared to other productd that were calculated in the same way like s1 ={1} , s2={2,4,8} sum1=1 , sum2=14 and the product is 14 and so on.

My code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () 
{
    int a[10000]; // Max value expected.
    int x;
    int y;
    cin >> x;
    cin >> y;
    int xexpy = 1;
    int k;

    for (int i = 0; i <= y; i++)
    {
        xexpy = 1;
        k = i;

        while(k > 0)
        { 
            xexpy = xexpy * x;
            k--;
        }

        cout << "\n" << xexpy;
        a[i] = xexpy;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please specify exactly what problems the code you have provided has - and what you expect it to do.

Comment: "divide", how?  All partitions, left-right of a sliding boundary, what?  A sample correct output for sample input would help.

Comment: no actually its a complete problem which I cant solve it .. and the code is only what I did till now .. an stopped because I don't know what to do

Comment: well suppose x=2 , y=3
s= {1,2,4,8}
one of the divisions is to take s1 ={1,4} , s2={2,8}
sum1=5 , sum2= 10 
the product is 50
and that will be compared to other productd that were calculated in the same way like s1 ={1} , s2={2,4,8} sum1=1 , sum2=14 and the produt is 14 
and so so so ..

Comment: Okay, for each 2-partition of `s` into `s1` and `s2` you want the product of the two sums of the elements of `s1` and `s2` and your task is to find the largest?

Comment: yes exactly ... no its the very very begining

Comment: The code you've given is not close to what you're asking for. Set partitioning needs an all-combinations iterator, constructing one of those is a useful exercise in itself.

Comment: and that's what I dont know how to do

Comment: Your use of terminology and symbols is unclear. What is a "partial group"? How are there multiple groups to divide rather than a single one? What is <sup>(2)</sup> as opposed to <sup>(2)</sup> or x<sup>2 ? Without a clear idea of what you're saying we can't provide an answer.

Comment: @einpoklum can you please have a looke on the example I've just put

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this reads more like a math problem than an actual programming problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a programming problem, it is a combinatorics problem with a theoretical rather than an empirical approach to its solution. You can simply print the correct solution and not bother iterating over any partitions.

Why is that?

Let

[image]

i.e. z is the fraction of the sum of all s elements that's in s<sub>1</sub>. It holds that

[image]

and thus, the product of both sets satisfies:

[image]

As a function of z (not of x and y), this is a parabola that takes its maximum at z = 1/2; and there are no other local maximum points, i.e. getting closer to 1/2 necessarily increases that product. Thus what you want to do is partition the full set so that each of s<sub>1</sub> and s<sub>2</sub> are as close as possible to have half the sum of elements.

In general, you might have had to use programming to consider multiple subsets, but since your elements are given by a formula - and it's the formula of a [geometric sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression).

First, let's assume x >= 2 and y >= 2, otherwise this is not an interesting problem.

Now, for x >= 2, we know that

[image]

(the sum of a geometric sequence), and thus

[image]

i.e. the last element always outweighs all other elements put together. That's why you always want to choose {x<sup>y</sup>} as s<sub>1</sub> and as all other elements as s<sub>2</sub>. No need to run any program. You can then also easily calculate the optimum product-of-sums.

---

Note: If we don't make assumptions about the elements of s, except that they're non-negative integers, finding the optimum solution is an optimization version of the [Partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) - which is NP-complete. That means, very roughly, that there is no solution is fundamentally much more efficient than just trying all possible combinations.

Comment: @plusplus: See edit, I hope I'm explaining it better now.

Comment: do you mean z= (the sum of s2 / sum of s) ??
And their product  ,isn't it is z * (1-z) * (the sum of all elements)^2

Comment: Hi .. I'm so sorry but it's not accepted as a solution of the assignment ..
"it isn't about getting a certain result, but rather getting that result in a specific way ".. prof said :|
so could you please help me out

Comment: @plusplus: Your professor was too lazy to properly design a homework assignment. Yes, you can artificially go through all sorts of subsets of s in one way or another, and end up with the same result, but there's not much sense in it. Ask him "Do you want a dynamic programming solution, or a brute force solution, which ignore the composition of s?" If the answer is 'yes' then you can very well consider jthill's answer - which is a fine "cheesy" solution as he defines it.

Comment: well I already asked him and he said nope .. and he added that I can solve it using for loops

Comment: @plusplus : jthill's solution does that, essentially. One for loops is visible already, and two more loops are  just "hidden" in library function calls (`fill_n()` and `next_permutation()`). Think about how you would implement them.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a cheesy all-combinations-of-supplied-arguments generator, provided without comment or explanation because I think this is homework, and the exercise of understanding how and why this does what it does is the point here.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main(int c, const char **v)
{
    basic_string<const char *> options(v);
    auto N(options.length());
    for (auto n = 1u; n < N; ++n) {
        vector<char> pick(N);
        fill_n(pick.rbegin(), n, 1);
        do for (auto j=1u; j<N; ++j)
            if (pick[j])
                cout << options[j]<<' ';
        while (cout<<'\n', next_permutation(begin(pick)+1, end(pick)));
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry but there are so many stuff that I'm not familiar with .. is there any solution simpler ...
and by the way I tried running it on DEV and it didn't work

Comment: It's not the answer to your assignment, but it does iterate through all combinations of its arguments, I just tested it.  Reread the clause after "because" above. You're going to have to put effort in to this.  Whether or not this is homework, if you're going to use C++ you're going to need to understand fundamentals like the library vectors and strings and algorithms.

Comment: oh god .. I really don't get it

Comment: and actually I'm not looking forward beeing a c++ prof ... no it's just a secondary course and I am obliged to solve homworks and stuff

Comment: +1 because this is nicely implemented using the standard library; -1 because you are `using namespace std` which isn't very educational; and +1 because it sounds like OP's professor might have wanted something like this after all.